# Docker-Sync issue : Can't have simultaneous environments anymore since 0.4.2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Since I've updated my Docker-Sync version to 0.4.0, then 0.4.1 and 0.4.2, it's getting worse every time.

I tried to switch to `navive_osx` mode as told, and the sync didn't work with the 0.4.0. The logs were fine, but the sync didn't happen anymore. So I came back to the Unison sync strategy.

I've set the `:nocopy` statement instead of `:rw` in docker compose for the volumes as the changelog asked with the 0.4.1 with no improvement.

Now with the 0.4.2 I can't even launch the environment at the same time. Whenever I am launching in a new terminal the second one, everything is getting mixed up in the first docker-sync window as you can see :

````
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:19.944798Z 0 [Note] Giving 2 client threads a chance to die gracefully
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:19.944837Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
ENV1_redis | 1:signal-handler (1494457519) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
ENV1_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:19.959 # User requested shutdown...
ENV1_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:19.959 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
ENV1_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:19.964 * DB saved on disk
ENV1_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:19.964 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.074Z 1 TID-qhhnw ERROR: Error fetching job: Error connecting to Redis on redis:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.074Z 1 TID-qhhnw ERROR: /bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:345:in `rescue in establish_connection'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.074Z 1 TID-qhhnw ERROR: /bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:331:in `establish_connection'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.074Z 1 TID-qhhnw ERROR: /bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:101:in `block in connect'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.074Z 1 TID-qhhnw ERROR: /bundle/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'

(.... ENV1_job tons of log...)

ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.255Z 1 TID-qhiv8 ERROR: /bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:88:in `get_one'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.256Z 1 TID-qhiv8 ERROR: /bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:98:in `fetch'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.256Z 1 TID-qhiv8 ERROR: /bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:81:in `process_one'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.256Z 1 TID-qhiv8 ERROR: /bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:70:in `run'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.256Z 1 TID-qhiv8 ERROR: /bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:20.256Z 1 TID-qhiv8 ERROR: /bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:26:in `block in safe_thread'
ENV1_redis exited with code 0
ENV2_redis | 1:C 10 May 23:05:21.731 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
ENV2_redis |                 _._
ENV2_redis |            _.-``__ ''-._
ENV2_redis |       _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.2.8 (00000000/0) 64 bit
ENV2_redis |   .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
ENV2_redis |  (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
ENV2_redis |  |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
ENV2_redis |  |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 1
ENV2_redis |   `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
ENV2_redis |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
ENV2_redis |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
ENV2_redis |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
ENV2_redis |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
ENV2_redis |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
ENV2_redis |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
ENV2_redis |       `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
ENV2_redis |           `-._        _.-'
ENV2_redis |               `-.__.-'
ENV2_redis |
ENV2_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:21.735 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
ENV2_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:21.735 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.8
ENV2_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:21.735 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
ENV2_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:21.740 * DB loaded from disk: 0.004 seconds
ENV2_redis | 1:M 10 May 23:05:21.740 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.946243Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 2 remaining clients
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.946330Z 0 [Warning] mysqld: Forcing close of thread 4  user: 'root'
ENV1_mysql |
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.946665Z 0 [Warning] mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3  user: 'root'
ENV1_mysql |
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.947247Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.947988Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962498Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962585Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962606Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962623Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962639Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962668Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962682Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962710Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962733Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962747Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962778Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962791Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962804Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962822Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962835Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962875Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962886Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962896Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962904Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962914Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962924Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962937Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962985Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.962997Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963007Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963016Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963045Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963054Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963063Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963071Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963081Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963094Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963128Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963149Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963163Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963427Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:21.963841Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:22.066175Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:22.070328Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170510 23:05:22
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.069Z 1 TID-qhjgc ERROR: heartbeat: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.495794Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 209478342
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497199Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497241Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497249Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497259Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497263Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497268Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497629Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497651Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.497987Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
ENV1_mysql | 2017-05-10T23:05:23.501084Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
ENV1_mysql |
ENV1_mysql exited with code 0
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:25.488Z 1 TID-5ccjc INFO: Shutting down
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:25.488Z 1 TID-5ccjc INFO: Terminating quiet workers
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:25.488Z 1 TID-qhjas INFO: Scheduler exiting...
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:25.989Z 1 TID-5ccjc INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.401023Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.407562Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 1 ...
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.413174Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.417101Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.417219Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.417228Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.417615Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.417853Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.417876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.419199Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.420183Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.424034Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.439491Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.441642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.506532Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.849378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.852156Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.941263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.949972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.950017Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:26.950423Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.001600Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 33405165
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.001924Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.004603Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.133456Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.165752Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.171471Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.171547Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.171563Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.171613Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.231101Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170510 23:05:27
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.299944Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.300034Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.304521Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.305993Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.420660Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
ENV1_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.494Z 1 TID-5ccjc INFO: Bye!
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.788719Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.790225Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
ENV2_sql | Version: '5.7.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.790320Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:27.790330Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
ENV1_job exited with code 0
ENV2_sql | 2017-05-10T23:05:28.588345Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
ENV2_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:32.681Z 1 TID-afb0o INFO: Running in ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
ENV2_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:32.681Z 1 TID-afb0o INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
ENV2_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:32.681Z 1 TID-afb0o INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
ENV2_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:32.682Z 1 TID-afb0o INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.2.10 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379"}
ENV2_job | 2017-05-10T23:05:32.690Z 1 TID-afb0o INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
ENV2_web | The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
ENV2_web | => Booting Puma
ENV2_web | => Rails 5.1.0.rc2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
ENV2_web | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
ENV2_web | Puma starting in single mode...
ENV2_web | * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Sassy Salamander
ENV2_web | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
ENV2_web | * Environment: development
ENV2_web | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
ENV2_web | Use Ctrl-C to stop
An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
EXCEPTION: #<Docker::Compose::Error: 'up' failed with status 'pid 77888 exit 1': Attaching to ENV1_mysql, ENV1_redis, ENV1_web, ENV1_job>
MESSAGE: 'up' failed with status 'pid 77888 exit 1': Attaching to ENV1_mysql, ENV1_redis, ENV1_web, ENV1_job
````

And everything shuts down.

## ENV1 configuration:

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: env1_mysql
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./data/sql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
      MYSQL_USER: rails
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: rails
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  redis:
    container_name: env1_redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data

  web:
    container_name: env1_web
    build: .
    command: sh scripts/start-dev.sh
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - env1-web-sync:/app:nocopy
      - env1-bundle-sync:/bundle:nocopy
      # - env1-static-sync:/static:ro
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
      DB_USER: rails
      DB_PASSWORD: rails
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true

  job:
    container_name: env1_job
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - env1-web-sync:/app:nocopy
      - env1-bundle-sync:/bundle:nocopy
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
    links:
      - db
      - redis

volumes:
  env1-web-sync:
    external: true
  env1-bundle-sync:
    external: true
```

**Docker-sync**

```
version: '2'
options:
  compose-file-path: 'docker-compose.yml'
syncs:
  env1-web-sync:
    src: './ENV1'
    sync_strategy: 'unison'
    sync_excludes: [ '.git', '.idea', 'tmp/*' ]
  env1-bundle-sync:
    src: './bundle'
    sync_strategy: 'unison'
```

## ENV2 configuration:

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: env2_sql
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./data/sql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
      MYSQL_USER: rails
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: rails
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  redis:
    container_name: env2_redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data

  web:
    container_name: env2_web
    build: .
    command: sh scripts/start-dev.sh
    volumes:
      - env2-web-sync:/app:nocopy
      - env2-bundle-sync:/bundle:nocopy
      - env2-static-sync:/static:nocopy
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
      MYSQL_USER: rails
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: rails
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true

  java:
    container_name: env2_java
    image: java:openjdk-8
    volumes:
      - env2-java-sync:/app:nocopy
    links:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true

  job:
    container_name: env2_job
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - env2-web-sync:/app:nocopy
      - env2-bundle-sync:/bundle:nocopy
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
    links:
      - db
      - redis


volumes:
  env2-web-sync:
    external: true
  env2-bundle-sync:
    external: true
  env2-static-sync:
    external: true
  env2-java-sync:
    external: true
```

**Docker-sync:**

```
version: "2"
options:
  compose-file-path: 'docker-compose.yml'
syncs:
  env2-web-sync:
    src: './ENV2'
    sync_strategy: 'unison'
    sync_excludes: [ '.git', '.idea', 'tmp/*' ]
  env2-bundle-sync:
    src: './bundle'
    sync_strategy: 'unison'
  env2-static-sync:
    src: '../static'
    sync_strategy: 'unison'
  env2-java-sync:
    src: './java'
    sync_strategy: 'unison'
```

Answer (score 0):

please upgrade to 0.4.5, this should fix your issues. Reconsider native_osx - its generally a lot better then the old unison way, especially with regard on CPU usage.

In any way, check your sync_excludes syntax, since "Name" is used by default, 'tmp/*' is wrong. Either use tmp or use 
https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/blob/master/example/docker-sync.yml#L75

```
sync_excludes_type: 'none'
sync_excludes: [ 'Name .git', 'Path .idea', 'Path tmp' ]
```

0.4.x was quiet a hard ride, i understand your frustration, see https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/issues/370 for the background story

Comment: Thanx for your answer and your project !
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the docker-sync gem and the native_osx seems to work perfectly... But I still have a collision between both Docker environments.

Comment: When I launch the ENV2, here is what I get in the terminal :
`(...)
Recreating ENV1_mysql
Recreating ENV1_redis
Recreating ENV1_web
Recreating ENV1_job
Creating ENV2_java
(...)` and in the other window (ENV1), everything shuts.

Comment: you most probably picking up the wrong configuration during the ENV2 startup. try doing `docker-sync list` prior starting ENV2 and ensure he lists the right syncs. Also, env1/evn2 - how are those in terms on where is the docker-sync.yml located? be aware, a .docker-sync folder is created next to ds.yml, which has a pid of the started process. If both configurations are in the same root, you could have issues with that ( the so called daemon mode )

Comment: **ENV1:**
`ok  Found configuration at /Users/cornelius/www/ENV1/rails/docker-sync.yml
ENV1-web-sync  On address :
ENV1-bundle-sync  On address :`

**ENV2:**
`ok  Found configuration at /Users/cornelius/www/ENV2/rails/docker-sync.yml
ENV2-web-sync  On address :
ENV2-bundle-sync  On address :
ENV2-static-sync  On address :
ENV2-java-sync  On address :`

Comment: You did not answer my questions :)

Comment: ah ? sorry :) this was the `docker-sync list` response for both environments.
They are not in the same root. `/www/ENV1/rails` and `/www/ENV2/rails` with in each directory docker-sync.yml and docker-compose.yml. Hope I answered the questions :)